# javascript find the nth occurence and add an underscore before it

Tags: javascript

Give this:

```
ForeclosureDefenseDate
ForeclosureDefense
```

I would like this:

```
foreclosure_defense_date
foreclosure_defense
```

This is what I wrote so far:

```
"ForeclosureDefense".replace(/(?:[A-Z])(?:[a-z]+)[A-Z]/g, "_");
```

It returns this output:

```
_efense
```

Basically what I tried to do above is match a capital, ignore it, and then match lowercase letters and ignore those as well, and then find a capital letter and that's when I take the action to replace with lowercase.

The issue I am having is it replaces the nth capital letter rather than appending an underscore before it, and also the second non-capturing should be ignoring the lowercase letters but it is not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `replace` takes a callback, that exposes the capture groups, try with `/([A-Z])([a-z]+)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace()` will replace the whole match, non-capture groups have nothing to do with that. It seems rather matching a lower case letter, you want to see if the capital letter *is followed* by a lower case letter. You can do this via a [**positive lookeahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=...)`).

As @elclanrs said, [**`.replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a callback as replacement:

```
str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?=[a-z])/g, function(match, index) {
    return (index > 0 ? '_' : '') +  match.toLowerCase();
});
```

Alternatively without callback:

```
str.replace(/[A-Z]+(?=[a-z])/g, '_$&').replace(/^_/, '').toLowerCase();
```

---

If you have names with acronyms and want to separate them so that e.g. `SomeURITestCase` would become `some_uri_test_case`, you can use

```
/[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[a-z])/g
```

as expression.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `/[A-Z]/g`

Comment: Depends on whether `URITestCase` should be converter to `uritest_case` or `u_r_i_test_case`. I guess the positive lookahead is not really necessary though. Actually, `URITestCase` should probably be `uri_test_case`, which can be achieved with `/[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[a-z])/g`.